# Xamarin.Android: Show image when app goes to the background

Tags: xamarin.android

friends I have a question,
Is it possible, when Xamarin.Android app goes to the background, in that case, show custom background image,
For example in this [In Android chrome is background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wlLB.png) picture see google chrome app in the background, I want to show in this case my custom image.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The default setting is when your app goes to the background, the OS, will take a screenshot and use this as a preview of your app.

In case of android you can not put a security image over the content when the app goes from foreground to background. The only thing you can do is that you can display a white screen. And this can be done by setting the same flag what is used to block capturing of screen shot.

Use the code below in OnCreate method after `LoadApplication`.

```
   Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Secure, WindowManagerFlags.Secure);
```